# git-svn ignores http proxy (debian)

Tags: linux, proxy, git-svn

Searching how to use git with a proxy I found two solutions:

- the http_proxy environment variable
- the git config http.proxy

Since `export http_proxy=http://proxy.fqdn:8080` made `wget` work, but not `git-svn`, I tried the second option additionally: `git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.fqdn:8080`. But to no success. Wireshark still tells me that git-svn contacts the remote repository directly. Alas:

```
git svn clone -s http://svn.wp-plugins.org/yak-for-wordpress 
ZM-Schicht Anforderung gescheitert: OPTIONS von »http://svn.wp-plugins.org/yak-for-wordpress«: Konnte keine Verbindung zum Server herstellen (http://svn.wp-plugins.org) at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 1916
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in git-svn? Did anyone try successfuly to clone a svn repo through a proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have to specify your username and password as well (in addition to the proxy address).

But also consider adding that same information (`http.proxy`) to SVN itself (as in [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/msysgit@googlegroups.com/msg00745.html)):

> Adding proxy information in the `[global]` section in `$HOME/.subversion/servers` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks very much. Setting the proxy for SVN itself did the trick. I guess I'll raise a request for the git-svn man page.